Is it computationally too expensive to verify a signature and perform 2 storage reads within a SignedExtension?
I'm working on a custom SignedExtension that needs to verify certain conditions as part of the transaction validation process (fn validate). The extension performs two key operations:

It verifies a signature on a small piece of data (less than 3KB) that is included in the transaction.
It performs 2 storage reads to validate some additional conditions

I have the following concerns regarding the potential performance impact of this approach:
Is verifying a signature (like ECDSA or Sr25519) within a SignedExtension too computationally intensive, given that the signer doesn't pay fees? Would this increase block production or transaction processing time significantly?
Are storage reads in a SignedExtension considered efficient enough, or could they pose a bottleneck during transaction validation?
